# Flask templates don't refresh and styles don't aply

Tags: html, css, flask

I,ve been coding a website with flask, I applied the styles:

```
:root{
--minion-yellow:#F4E04D;
--white:#fcfcfc;
--fluorescent-blue:#54f2f2;
--maximum-blue:#5eb1bf;
--rich-black:#042a2b;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
background:var(--minion-yellow);
}
```

and it works, then I changed some things:

```
:root{
--white:#fcfcfc;
--fluorescent-blue:#54f2f2;
--maximum-blue:#5eb1bf;
--rich-black:#042a2b;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a{
text-decoration: none;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

header{
    background: var(--maximum-blue);
    padding: 3px;
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px ;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.centered{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 2%;
    background:var(--white);
}
```

but the background is still yellow, and the debbug is on.
I also tried changing files, refreshing the server, and remaking files(Delete and remake)

halp me :'v

Answer (score 0):

Should be static files cached problem of the browser, try refreshing the page with `Shift+F5` and see if it works.